# How to get Bar instance?

Tags: jquery

I have a Bar class:

```
function Bar() {
    this.myMethod = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ...,
            success: function(msg){
                // I can't get Bar instance with 'this'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If ajax is succeeded, I want to do something with Bar instance. What should I do? Create var for the instance outside ajax call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Bar() {
    var self = this;
    this.myMethod = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ...,
            success: function(msg){
                //Use self here.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes as my thought, we have to add a variable. I'm looking for the simpler one. Btw, you use `self` keyword as variable name?

Comment: I can't see it being much simpler than that. You can use what ever name you like for the variable, I just like to keep it relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a variable, like Alex suggests, or create a wrapper function that contains the closure:

```
[...]
this.myMethod = function () {
   $.ajax({
            ...,
            success: (function (context) {
              return function(msg){
                //Use context here.
              }
            }(this))
        });

   }
[...]
```

However, if you want to keep it simple, I'd go with Alex's suggestion, since it is more obvious what happens.

Comment: ok I'm using his suggestion.. but I do really know about this technique, thanks!